# Merge and Append columns for more than 2 files

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, paste

[image: I have "N" number of files with the contents shown in the image, and I want to merge and append the 5th column]

The files are tab separated.

I have "N" number of files whose contents are as shown in the screenshot above. I want to merge them and append the 5th column. The first 4 columns are the same.

I tried with the `awk` command below for files 1 and 2:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;next} {print a[FNR] "\t",$5}' file1 file2
```

it only appends for 2 files, not more than 2.

How can I do this correctly using `awk`, `paste` or other tools?

Comment: remove the picture of your data and add your actual data. Make it easy for us to reproduce your code.

Comment: I did not get your need, you ask to add the 5th column from file2 to file1?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and i) replace the screenshot with the actual text so we can copy it and test our solutions. ii) explain what you want to happen with the multiple files. If you have 12 files, should the 5th column of all of them be included? iii) Do all the files have the exact same entries and only the 5th column is missing?

Comment: Hi i tried to add the 2 file content in a tabular format, but the indentation is getting mess as normal text so had to take screen shot. and Yes i want to append the only 5th column

Answer (score 2):

Without testing:

```
awk -F "\t" '
    { key = $1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4; values[key] = values[key] FS $5 }
    END { for (key in values) print key values[key] }
' file ...
```

---

The header

For each file, you  want to extract part of the filename and use that as the header. We'll keep track of the header with a separate string, appending to it for each file.

```
awk -F "\t" '
    BEGIN { header = "col1" FS "col2" FS "col3" FS "col4" }
    { 
        key = $1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4
        values[key] = values[key] FS $5 
    }
    FNR == 1 { 
        split(FILENAME, a, /_/)
        header = header FS a[2] 
    }
    END { 
        print header
        for (key in values) 
            print key values[key] 
    }
' file ...
```

We initialize the header in the BEGIN block. Give the first 4 columns whatever header titles you require.

The variable `FNR` is the record number of the current file. When `FNR == 1` we are on the first line of this file. The awk variable `FILENAME` holds the name of the file currently being processed.

---

Sorting

If you use GNU awk then you can do this in the END block ([reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html#Controlling-Scanning)):

```
    END { 
        print header
        # order the array by index, as strings, ascending
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"
        for (key in values) 
            print key values[key] 
    }
```

If you don't have GNU awk, you can do this:

```
awk '...' | {
    read header
    echo "$header"
    sort
}
```

Comment: I think the OP's column 4 differs from file to file and the key is the first 2 fields. So this would munge the output.  Easily fixed.

Comment: The  fact that im on a mobile and can't read... or count

Comment: Hi Glen, thanks for the reply, its working fine, but to add on to it, while appending can we keep header as its file name so as to track from which file its been appended, i have all file names as "P4318_34071_LIB17790_NMPNL.Coverage_AvrgDep.bed" want to split file name with "_", and keep header as 2nd element i.e "34071" Thank you

Comment: @Glen Is it also possible to keep the order of the 1st 4 columns same in the output, because 1st 4 columns are identical across all the files as shown in above sample file. Thank you

Comment: Yes, both those things are possible. Have you done any research about how to implement them?

Comment: Hi Glen, i know there is split function "echo *.bed | awk '{split($0,a,"_"); print a[2] }'", as i am new to shell scripting to loop them hash ( key values ) which i am aware how to do in " Perl" Prog language but in shell not sure when and how to use the syntax specially there are multiple things process at once. Anyways Thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks a ton Glen, with just your command could learn many so i can reuse them (Syntax) for other purpose. Thanks a lot for the explanation too

Comment: I appreciate your kind words. The way to express gratitude on stackoverflow and related sites is to hand out reputation points. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

If the first four columns are identical across files you could run something like

```
set -- file*
fields="-f-5,$(seq -s, 10 5 $((5*$#)))"
paste "$@" | cut ${fields%?} >outfile
```

This will `paste` all files then extract fields 1-5 and every 5th field after.

Comment: Hi, I tried with above command but it gave error as " cut: you must specify a list of bytes, characters, or fields"

Comment: Its cut (GNU coreutils) 8.4