# Paste different csv files

Tags: text-processing, csv, paste, table

I have a bunch of input csv files (delimited with semi-colon "`;`" having the following format

```
YEAR;MONTH;DAY;RES1FILE1;RES2FILE1;RES3FILE1
1901;01;01;101;154;169
1901;01;02;146;174;136
```

The number of columns for each files is variable, meaning that some files could have 6 columns and some others 4.

I would like to paste each files into one big csv file (with "`;`" as a delimiter. My problem is that, in order to avoid redundancy, I would like to avoid pasting the first three column each time since for every files they are the same (`YEAR;MONTH;DAY`).

Therefore the output should look like this:

```
YEAR;MONTH;DAY;RES1FILE1;RES2FILE1;RES3FILE1;RES1FILE2;RES2FILE2
1901;01;01;101;154;169;185;165
1901;01;02;146;174;136;129;176
```

I am currently using the following command:

```
arr=( *_rcp8p5.csv )
paste "${arr[@]}" | cut -f-4,$(seq -s, 8 4 $((4*${#arr[@]}))) >out_rcp8p5.txt
```

But it is not working at all

Comment: What _exactly_ do you mean by "paste"? Edit the question and add an example of the input _and_ output.

Comment: @Kusalananda - most likely OP wants to do [the same (or similar) thing as here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/252481) only this time the no. of columns in each file may vary.

Comment: What you need is [the `join` command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/join.html).  Except you don't seem to have a primary key (unique identifier) for each record.  I guess you want to use the line number for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two ways to approach this:

1. implement your own 'paste' that skips the first three fields of all but the first file - for example

   ```
   awk -F\; '
     FNR==NR {
       a[FNR]=$0; next;
     }
     {
       for (i=4;i<=NF;i++) a[FNR] = sprintf("%s;%s", a[FNR], $i);
     } 
     END {
       for (n=1;n<=FNR;n++) print a[n];
     }' file*.csv
   ```
2. paste the files together, then retain fields based on an indicator derived from the header row

   ```
   paste -d\; file*.csv | 
     perl -MList::MoreUtils=indexes -F\; -alne '
       @keep = indexes { $_ !~ /YEAR|MONTH|DAY/ } @F if $. == 1; 
       print join ";", @F[0..2,@keep]'
   ```

   (if you don't have the `List::MoreUtils` module, you should be able to implement the same functionality using perl's `grep`).

Comment: Both options work just perfectly! If you do have a little bit of time to explain the different command used it could be really great! Thank you very much.